# "CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32 not defined or empty" while rebuilding Android Kernel

Tags: cross-compiling, android-source, android-kernel

I'm trying to rebuild Kernel for Sony XZ based on Android Pie, but there is a error occuring like below. Message says " CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32 not defined or empty, the compat vDSO will not be built", it means I have to find 32-bit toolchains for compiling compat vDSO supported in Android Pie and set CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32 to an appropriate value. But I haven't yet found that toolchains so far. Can anybody help me?

```
arch/arm64/Makefile:83: *** CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32 not defined or empty, the compat vDSO will not be built.  Stop.
```

Thank All !

Answer (score 0):

during the script you need this before it starts compiling

```
export CC_FOR_BUILD=clang
```

Comment: Thank you ! I have tried that but still get failed with same error message

Comment: I implemented following this tutorial from sony, please watch in this link for 64 bit device: https://developer.sony.com/develop/open-devices/guides/kernel-compilation-guides/how-to-build-and-flash-a-linux-kernel-for-aosp-supported-devices#AutoLinuxKernel

Answer (score 0):

I had to change `CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO=y` to `CONFIG_COMPAT_VDSO=n` in the kernel config.